# Form Not Submitting In Windows Phone 7 (IE)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, windows-phone-7, onclick

I have been developing my website from scratch and have ran into a problem with the native browser on Windows Phone 7.

I have built a form that is submitted through a javascript function via. an anchor tag onclick event, using the JQuery .submit() function. The browser seems to load then hangs without ever completing the form post. Does anyone know why this happens? And is there a better alternative?

Comment: You could try to remove the void(0) and add `submit(); return false;` to the `onclick` event...

Comment: I don't have a Windows Phone 7 here but try to analyse the problem with http://jsconsole.com

Comment: Asking people to visit your website to debug an issue can be considered spam.

Comment: Don't know why this was closed, I have run into this problem several times in a website I am working on. It's not PHP specific but it seems like Windows phone doesn't like javscript:void(0). If I use return false in the click handler instead it's fine.